# Como buscar con recursion?

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos tengo esta situacion:
Recibo en una funcion como parametro un arreglo de objetos y debo devolver la propiedad 'taquillera' que tengan como valor true en un arreglo pero tengo que recorrer el array de forma recursiva.
La funcion en cuestion es esta

```
  function peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux = [], i=0) {}
```

y mi objeto a recorrer este :

```
var peliculas =
 [{
 nombre: "Los pitufos",
 añoDeEstreno: "2011",
 genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
 taquillera: false
 },
 {
  nombre: "Avengers: La era de Ultrón",
añoDeEstreno: "2015",
 genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
 taquillera: true
 },{
  nombre: "Alicia",
 añoDeEstreno: "2015",
 genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
 taquillera: true
}]
```

Hasta ahora intente utilizar una cumulador que me valla pusheando las peliculas con la propiedad true asi:

```
function peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux = [], i=0) {

if(peliculas[i].taquillera === true){
 aux += aux.push(peliculas[i])
}else {
 return peliTaquillera(peliculas[i], aux, ++i)
 }
    return aux
 }
```

Pero no me funciona.
Ayuda plisss!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer así:

```js
var peliculas = [{
    nombre: "Los pitufos",
    añoDeEstreno: "2011",
    genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
    taquillera: false
  },
  {
    nombre: "Avengers: La era de Ultrón",
    añoDeEstreno: "2015",
    genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
    taquillera: true
  }, {
    nombre: "Alicia",
    añoDeEstreno: "2015",
    genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
    taquillera: true
  }
]

function peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux = [], i = 0) {
  if(!peliculas[i]){ 
    //Si el inidice a buscar no existe es que ya no hay mas elementos en el array
    return aux; //Retornas lo que lleves acumulado
  } //De lo contrario el indice i si existe


  if (peliculas[i].taquillera === true) {
    //Si esa pelicula del indice i es taquillera la acumulas en aux
    aux.push(peliculas[i])
  }
  
  //Aqui va la recursion:
  //Devuelves el mismo proceso pero para el siguiente elemento ++i
  return peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux, ++i)
}

console.log(peliTaquillera(peliculas))
```

Comment: Me sirve mucho ver como interpretan los demás el código.Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Explicación en comentarios:

```js
const peliculas = [{
        nombre: "Los pitufos",
        añoDeEstreno: "2011",
        genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
        taquillera: false
    },
    {
        nombre: "Avengers: La era de Ultrón",
        añoDeEstreno: "2015",
        genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
        taquillera: true
    }, {
        nombre: "Alicia",
        añoDeEstreno: "2015",
        genero: "Fantasia/Aventura/Acción",
        taquillera: true
    }
]

function peliculasTaquilleras(p, aux = []) {

    // condición de finalización de la recursión
    if (p.length == 0) return aux;

    // se evalúa el primer elemento del arreglo
    if (p[0].taquillera) aux.push(p[0])

    // paso recursivo
    // se reduce el arreglo en cada llamada con slice
    // hasta llegar al arreglo vacío de la condición de fin
    return peliculasTaquilleras(p.slice(1), aux)
}

console.log(peliculasTaquilleras(peliculas))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No creo que la recursividad sea la forma más directa para hacer lo que quieres, porque los datos no están anidados. Tienes una lista que vas recorriendo en el mismo nivel. Puedes hacer algo así

```
var taquilleras = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= length(peliculas); i++)
    if(peliculas[i].taquillera)
        taquilleras.push(peliculas[i]);
```

Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo recursivamente, observa lo que hace tu código: si la película no es taquilera, entonces devuelve un resultado. Eso no es lo que quieres: aún si te encuentras con una no taquillera, quieres seguir analizando la lista.

```
function peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux = [], i = 0) {
    if(peliculas[i].taquillera)
        aux.push(peliculas[i]);

    if(i < peliculas.length - 1)
        peliTaquillera(peliculas, aux, i + 1);

    return aux;
}
```

Observa que:

- En esta recursión no importa el valor que devuelve la función para niveles mayores al 0, porque la matriz `aux` va siendo modificada por cada llamada. `return aux` sólo importa para la llamada al nivel 0; de hecho, podría agregarse que el `return` sea condicional (`if(nivel == 0) return aux;`) pero tampoco nos afecta que quede así.
- No hace falta modificar el valor de `i`, sino sólo enviar el valor aumentado al siguiente nivel;
- No se envía `peliculas[i]` al siguiente nivel de recursión, porque la función espera una matriz.
- En la recursividad se requiere una condición para saber cuándo parar (en este caso es `i < peliculas.length - 1`, si no, harás llamadas hasta que se desborde la pila.
- Se requiere más código en la versión recursiva que en la versión de bucle `for`.

Comment: Me quedo muy claro gracias !!!!